# Should I use routerLink only with anchors or is it okay to use it on other HTML elements too?

Tags: html, angular, semantics, routerlink

Let's say that I have a logo on my website, should I link it this way:

```
<a routerLink="/">
    <img src="logo.png" alt="logo">
</a>
```

or maybe like this:

```
<img src="logo.png" alt="logo" routerLink="/">
```

What about headlines?

```
<a [routerLink]="['/post', post.id]">
    <h3>Post title</h3>
</a>
```

versus

```
<h3 [routerLink]="['/post', post.id]">Post title</h3>
```

What is the proper way of handling this? Does it even matter? Is there any semantic value in adding HTML anchor tag if I'm using routerLink?

Comment: While it will still work you want to use anchor, as it will also bind to middle click, show user url before entering and other commonly forgotten things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Semantically speaking it is better to use an anchor than just an element. For accissibility reasons an anchor is more clear than just linking an element.

Comment: As far as I know since HTML5 it is valid to wrap block level elements in anchors: http://html5doctor.com/block-level-links-in-html-5/

Comment: Nice! Makes more sense as well when speaking of an accessibility point of view